# Deploy Replicas in specific ports and hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I need to deploy a docker container in a swarm. I want to deploy 4 replica of the docker container. I want to set the port which each container will run and I need to know their hostname.

What I would is to lunch 4 replicas.

- Replica 1 should listen to port 3001 and hostname slave1.
- Replica 2 should listen to port 3002 and hostname slave2.
- Replica 3 should listen to port 3003 and hostname slave3.
- Replica 4 should listen to port 3004 and hostname slave4.

Each replica has the same Dockerfile (because the process which I want to run is the same). In the Dockerfile I expose all the 4 ports using the standard command:
EXPOSE 3001 3002 3003 3004

I tried this docker-compose file where I use 4 ports and deploy using "mode:replicated"

```
services:
  slave:
    image: "DOCKER_REPO_NAME"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 4
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - my_net
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3002:3002"
      - "3003:3003"
      - "3004:3004"

networks:
  my_net:
    external: true
```

but it is not working as I would and as described above.

Hope the description of the problem makes sense. Please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding docker swarm mode respectively the way it is supposed to work. Swarm mode is not working on container / node level but it is one level of abstraction higher - it is working with services.

A service consists of a given count of instances of containers running on a given count of nodes. Swarm will handle how many container instances are running in the swarm and it will handle on which nodes the service's containers are running (of course you can configure that by using params like `replicas` and `constraints`).

A great benefit of swarm mode is that you don't need to know anything about the infrastructure of the swarm. You don't care about which nodes are there and which container is running on which node.

Instead you just tell the swarm what service you want to contact and swarm mode will decide to which container on which node it will dispatch your request.

So in your example if your service is running on port 3001 and let's say there is an api endpoint called `GET /hello` you would request http://slave:3001/hello. This is where swarm mode comes into play and because it knows which containers are running on which nodes, it will decide where your request will be forwarded to.

If you want to have specific containers listening to specific ports on specific nodes you have to define multiple services and configure those using [constraints and labels](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/admin/configure/add-labels-to-cluster-nodes/) .. so your docker-compose.yml would look something like:

```
services:
  slave1:
    image: "DOCKER_REPO_NAME"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == slave1
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - my_net
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
  slave2:
    image: "DOCKER_REPO_NAME"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == slave2
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - my_net
    ports:
      - "3002:3001"
  slave3:
    image: "DOCKER_REPO_NAME"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == slave3
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - my_net
    ports:
      - "3003:3001"
  slave4:
    image: "DOCKER_REPO_NAME"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == slave4
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - my_net
    ports:
      - "3004:3001"

networks:
  my_net:
    external: true
```

But be aware of the fact that this is destroying much of the benefits of swarm.

Comment: I understand your observation and thanks. I was reading an article about "docker service scale", It's not clear to me what is the difference between that command and the deploy mode replicated. Do you think "docker service scale" can solve my problem?

Comment: You are right - there is no difference. `docker service scale myservice=10` is the same as if you use `mode: replicated` and `replicas: 10`. Both are just influencing the count of running containers per defined service.

Comment: Note that you can define the common service parts once by using [extends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/) or [fragments](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/10-fragments/). The base service can be in the same file and shouldn't have ports defined (as they are added, not replaced). You can avoid starting the base service by adding a [profile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) for it.